# Analytics in Windows Phone 8.1 mobile app on Cordova

Tags: windows, cordova, google-analytics, windows-phone-8.1, flurry

I am struggling to find an analytical tool that would allow me to track usage frequency of my mobile app written in Cordova for Windows Phone 8.1. Is there anything you could recommend?

Flurry doesn't seem to handle such configuration, I couldn't make Google Analytics work. I have tried to use http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/ yet no data is uploaded to my Google Analytics dashboard.

This is an enterprise application, which isn't distributed via Marketplace.

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Have you considered Azure's Application Insights?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en will allow you to send all the tracking you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var TID = 'UA-XXXX';
var GA_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect';
var cid;

// Should be called after deviceReady
function init() {
    cid = device.uuid; // cordova-plugin-device is required
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var body = 'v=1&t=pageview&tid=' + TID + '&cid=' + cid + '&dp=%2Findex.html';
    xhr.open("POST", GA_ENDPOINT, true)
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log('asd');
    }
    xhr.send(body);
}

function sendEvent(category, action, label, value) {
    category = category && encodeURIComponent(category);
    action = action && encodeURIComponent(action);
    label = label && encodeURIComponent(label);
    value = value && encodeURIComponent(value);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var body = 'v=1&t=event&tid=' + TID + '&cid=' + cid +
        '&ec=' + category + '&ea=' + action + '&el=' + label + (value ? '&ev=' + value : '');
    xhr.open("POST", GA_ENDPOINT, true);
    xhr.send(body);
}
```

Useful links:

- [Measurement Protocol docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/)
- [Hit Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really useful. Although I have managed to configure Azure Insights, I'll probably switch to Google Analytics. For anyone interested in Azure Insights: http://blog.falafel.com/using-application-insights-with-cordova-apps-in-visual-studio/
https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-ms-appinsights Just keep in mind that it needs 1 day "warm-up"

Comment: @Wojtek, I'm curious what is the reason to switch from Azure Insights?

Comment: there are two: (1) I use GA for other projects (2) AI is still in preview mode, and for example today it is experiencing some problems with displaying tracking data

Comment: in the code you have posted, shouldn't pageviews be replaced with screenviews and four other mobile app-specific parameters added, as outlined here: http://www.daimto.com/monitoring-quota-usage-for-google-apis/ ?

Comment: Great article, thank you! You are right - I'll update the code when I have a moment.